# Moving a DOM node and browser repaint performance

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, browser, repaint

Say I have a page with a bunch of divs stack one after another. At one point, I move the 30th one from its position below up to position, say, 5. This causes the old nodes 5 to 29 to move down a slot.

Neglecting what's inside the divs, how much of a *relative* performance impact does this operation have? If I understood the repaint concept correctly, this would cause a big repaint since lots of visible items' positions are changed. But I thought something as simple would have been optimized by the browser using some tricks.

Disclaimer: I did try to test the repaint on Chrome, but I guess my method wasn't adequate enough, and I couldn't discern much.

*Here's the follow-up question:* say I move a few of these divs around. What would be better in terms of performance: moving each individually, or, say, just simply re-append every node? My thought is that, at a certain point, would it be better to just re-append the whole thing once, rather than moving 6 or 7 divs around and repaint around half the screen each time (if that's indeed the case).

Thanks.

Comment: Then this should be *tested* in [jsperf](http://http://jsperf.com/) or use [BenchmarkJS](http://benchmarkjs.com/).

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` as an "optimization" for "repainting" - it *may* actually make the browser have to do *more* work and parse the contents into a new DOM subtree. Alterations to the DOM, with existing nodes, skip this step. As long as the DOM nodes are moved *intelligently* (e.g. insert after and not some terrible O(n^2) loop), then it should be sufficiently fast for most cases. There is no performance issue unless there is a [verifiable] performance issue.

Comment: @user2246674 innerHTML was just an example because I couldn't come up with a quick way of saying this. I'll modify my post.

Comment: @chenglou Replace `innerHTML` with `someCleverHack` and my comment holds. Browsers are very fast at *reflowing* (positioning elements, say after a DOM or CSS update) and *repainting* (rendering the elements to the viewport). Very complex sites are rendered "in the blink of an eye"; there are some degenerate cases (e.g. deep nested tables that utilize "auto layout"), but don't "prematurely optimize".

Comment: @user2246674 thanks for the reply. I updated my question: forget innerHTML, what about just re-appending everything (that wouldn't be a hack, would it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read through this article a while back and it taught me a fair bit:

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/

eg:

*"
Apply animations to elements that are position fixed or absolute. They don’t affect other elements layout, so they will only cause a repaint rather than a full reflow. This is much less costly"*

There's loads more useful tips there aswell.